# Rewrite nginx rule for delete ID on url

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I need write a rule for delete id on url post (wordpress)

```
https://myqite.com/12-title-of-post-one
https://myqite.com/45-title-of-post-two
https://myqite.com/56-title-of-post-nn
```

to

```
https://myqite.com/title-of-post-one
https://myqite.com/title-of-post-two
https://myqite.com/title-of-post-nn
```

Try several options but fail.

```
rewrite ^([0-9]+)-(.+)$ $2 permanent;
```

Other

```
rewrite ^([0-9]+)-(.+)$ $2 last;
```

Comment: The regex `([0-9]+)` matches all numbers. What do you get when you replace `rewrite ^([0-9]+)-(.+)$ $2 last;` with `rewrite ^(.+)$ $2 last;`?

Comment: Regex work perfectly.  ([0-9]+- matches number of url such 59-. This element not like. It's first var o regex.  (.*) it's second part on var. That is a like url. ON post, it's very clean explained what I like. Thanks. http://rubular.com/r/pp4pjDZAac

Comment: `nginx` URIs begin with a leading `/`. You should probably use something like: `rewrite ^/[0-9]+-(.+)$ /$1`

Comment: `rewrite ^/[0-9]+-(.+)$ /$1 last;`not work. This line it's after other that work fine. `rewrite ^/sitemap_index.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;` `rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;`Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several test I get solution

```
location ~ /([0-9]+)-(.+) {
   return 301 https://$server_name/$2;
}
```